# How to include node_modules in a custom module which should remain private and outside of npm

Tags: node.js, npm

I am developing a node module that has to remain private and outside of npm but uses dependencies from npm. Right now I just have the node_modules folder inside the module folder, but that creates problems when working with git and I think it is not an elegant approach. Is there a better way to include the modules from npm?

Answer (score 0):

You can publish [private modules](https://docs.npmjs.com/private-modules/intro) on npm, it starts at $7/month.

Or you can use [git urls as dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies).